# Spark SQL: How to assign the same ID for a group of rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with users and their actions:

| User | Action |
| --- | --- |
| John | logged in |
| John | did smth |
| John | logged out |
| John | logged in |
| John | did smth |
| John | logged out |
| Patric | logged in |
| Patric | did smth |
| Patric | logged out |

I want to assign a session_id for every action between logging in and out:

| User | Action | Session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | logged in | 1 |
| John | did smth | 1 |
| John | logged out | 1 |
| John | logged in | 2 |
| John | did smth | 2 |
| John | logged out | 2 |
| Patric | logged in | 3 |
| Patric | did smth | 3 |
| Patric | logged out | 3 |

I think I should use lag window function, but I can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: Wouldn't you want session_id to start from 1 for every user?

Comment: How can you tell from the data in which order the actions came in? There is no intrinsic order in a Spark dataframe. I believe that the data should contain a timestamp or something similar

Comment: yeah, but this is ease to solve by ordering data by user and timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the solutions without using `lag` or `lead`; let us assume that `ds` is our main dataset; first, we have to create a unique ID:

```
ds = ds.withColumn("id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("user").partitionBy("user")))
```

Then we declare these window variables for the sake of clearance:

```scala
val sumWindow = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("id")
val sessionWindow = Window.orderBy("user", "inter")
```

Then, we create a cumulative count per `user` ordering by `id`, then finally, create the `session` column:

```scala
ds = ds
  .withColumn("inter",
    sum(when(col("action").equalTo("logged in"), 1).otherwise(0)).over(sumWindow)
  )
  .withColumn("session", dense_rank().over(sessionWindow))
```

Final output:

```
+------+----------+---+-----+-------+
|user  |action    |id |inter|session|
+------+----------+---+-----+-------+
|John  |logged in |1  |1    |1      |
|John  |did smth  |2  |1    |1      |
|John  |logged out|3  |1    |1      |
|John  |logged in |4  |2    |2      |
|John  |did smth  |5  |2    |2      |
|John  |logged out|6  |2    |2      |
|Patric|logged in |1  |1    |3      |
|Patric|did smth  |2  |1    |3      |
|Patric|logged out|3  |1    |3      |
+------+----------+---+-----+-------+
```

I kept `inter` and `id` so you can see what happens, hope this is useful, good luck!